# En el prefacio del libro Don Quixote, hay un frase: Donde eres señor della--¿qué significa?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario

En el prefacio--el prólogo--del libro Don Quixote, hay una frase: Donde eres señor della--¿qué significa? No puedo encontrar esta palabra (della) en ningún traductor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La voz "della" "**dello**" puede utilizarse con las siguientes acepciones;

**dello, lla**

1. Como contracción en desuso "**De ello**", "**De ella**".

"como el más pintado, y estás **en tu casa**, **donde eres señor della**, como el rey de sus alcabalas (como el rey lo es de los impuestos que recauda)"

"Donde eres señor della" - Donde eres señor de ella (**donde eres señor de tu casa**)

**dello con dello**

1. Expresión en desuso. Era usada para explicar que es preciso mezclar la dulzura con la severidad, sufrir los males con los bienes y tener templanza en todo lo que se hace.
2. Expresión coloquial en desuso. Era usada para expresar la mezcla de cosas opuestas entre sí.

https://dle.rae.es/dello

**Nota Alcabala**

*La alcabala fue un impuesto propio de la Corona de Castilla establecido por Alfonso XI del que sólo estuvo exento el clero; no se suprimió hasta 1845: cf. I, 45, 529, n. 64. ¶ CL II, 32, n. 41 explica el origen histórico de la frase, situándola en el gobierno de Isabel la Católica. RM VI:58n. Cf. también García de Valdeavellano [1968/73:597, 608], Lunenfeld [1987:75-79]. ¶ Ligada al refrán que viene a continuación, la alusión a la frase hecha puede tener un sentido irónico, si se piensa en el aumento de tributos que Felipe II hizo votar en las Cortes de Madrid de 1588, y en la declaración de deudas de Felipe III en las de 1602. Recuérdese que C. fue alcabalero en Andalucía y acabó en la cárcel.*

Answer (score 3):

Es contracción antigua de "de ella".

```
[...en tu casa], donde eres señor della =
[...en tu casa], donde eres señor de ella
```

Esta contracción, como las análogas "dél", "dello", "deste", "desta" y "desto" se usaban en español antiguo, pero no se consideran aceptables en la norma culta actual. Aún así, al menos estas formas singulares mantienen entradas en el Diccionario de la RAE:

["dello, lla"](https://dle.rae.es/dello)

["dél"](https://dle.rae.es/d%C3%A9l)

["deste, ta"](https://dle.rae.es/deste)

Comment: Curiosamente en México, de manera coloquial se usa con bastante frecuencia *deste, desta, dese* et al, cuando no recuerdas de primera mano los detalles o nombre de algún objeto, p.ej: **Por favor, trae las llaves del candado, las dejé en el *deste* debajo de la *desta* en la habitación.** Quien tenga cierta familiaridad con la disposición de tus cosas, de inmediato sabrá que te refieres al "cajón" (deste) bajo la televisión (desta), la única pista es el género de los objetos.